# How to solve this system of differential linear equations?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Im stuck on this exercise. I believe that the initial condition means to equal the concentrations A,B and C to 0 but other than that Im not sure how to proceed with the exercise.

[image]

Comment: Where IS thé problem ?

Comment: The initial value problem is really already written for you, as the equations and initial condition are both given. For solving it, you can either use eigenvalues and eigenvectors or you can just solve for $[A]$ and then $[B]$ and then $[C]$. Hopefully you have already seen at least one of these methods...